# Why is "vamos" used for command but not the imperative "vayamos"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, imperativo

I don't understand why people use *vamos* (present) to say "let's go", but not "vayamos" (imperative/subj. present).

Is there a special reason to use "vamos" (vámonos) instead of "vayamos" (vayámonos) to say "let's go" (let's leave)?

Comment: I never even realised that the imperative of "ir" is "vayamos" and not "vamos" :O

Comment: no es un duplicado!!!

Comment: Regarding the "correctness" described on the answers I've never seen anyone in Colombia saying "vayamos". It may exists in the language but nobody uses it here. The other two forms "vámonos" and "vamos" are used always. All spell checkers say _vámonos_ is misspelled (and it is) but that is the way we all speak in Colombia (as always with minor exceptions.)

Comment: @iBug - When a new question is posed that appears to be basically equivalent to an existing one, it usually helps to edit the question so it's clearly distinguishable from the other one, and/or give a persuasive argument. I'm voting to close; but I'm open to considering an explanation or reasoning.

Comment: I actually think the problem here is that the similar, older question didn't have a clear, satisfying answer.  I've tried to write one.  If I haven't nailed it I hope others will make a stab at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, it appears as if the RAE does not include first person plural in the conjugation of the imperative (see [conjugation of *ir*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=M5ucdgy), click on the blue button "conjugar"), so when we are using *vamos* it is not actually an imperative form, but the subjunctive used with an [**exhortative**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/exhortative) value.

So the question is, why use the imperative form *vamos* instead of the correct  subjunctive form *vayamos*?

Well, according to the **Diccionario Panhispánico de dudas**, [ir, point 2](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=ir):

> The form *vamos* is, nowadays, the first person plural of the present
>   indicative. [...] However, in medieval and classical Spanish it was, as well
>   as *vayamos*, the form of the first person plural of the present
>   **subjunctive**. [...]
>
> As a vestige of its former meaning, the form *vamos* is still used with an **exhortative** aim more often than *vayamos*. [...] As a matter of
>   fact, the form *vayamos*, with that meaning, has been almost relegated
>   to mere literary discourse. [...]

**TL;DR**: To sum up, in medieval Spanish both *vamos* and *vayamos* were valid forms for the subjunctive, but only the former has been kept in modern Spanish for exhortative sentences.

Comment: I had to look up exhortative! Now that I've double-checked, I feel even more strongly that this answer doesn't really help.

Comment: I have to disagree with the comment above.  It's actually a topic I hadn't given much thought to, but your answer was clearly enlightening and I appreciate the fact that you took the time to answer this question with not only reasoned thought, but cited, reputable sources.  Obviously, the original poster saw the value in your answer.  He gave you the green check mark.  Well done and well deserved.

Answer (score 6):

This passage from [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=qF8kh8sgID6Ifqj7vG) explains why "vamos" is used as an alternative of "vayamos" for imperative, first person plural:

> 2. La forma *vamos* es hoy la primera persona del plural del presente de indicativo: «Laureano y yo nos vamos al jardín» (Gallego Adelaida [Esp. 1990]); pero en el español medieval y clásico era, alternando con *vayamos*, forma de primera persona del plural del presente de subjuntivo: «Si vos queréys que vamos juntos, pongámoslo, luego, por obra» (Daza Antojos [Esp. 1623]). Como resto de su antiguo valor de subjuntivo, la forma *vamos* se emplea, con más frecuencia que *vayamos*, con finalidad exhortativa: «Vamos, Johnny, vamos a casa que es tarde» (Cortázar Reunión [Arg. 1983]); la forma de subjuntivo *vayamos*, con este sentido, ha quedado casi relegada a la lengua literaria: «Vayámonos de aquí» (Amestoy Durango [Esp. 1989]). Lo que no debe hacerse en ningún caso es emplear hoy la forma *vamos*, en lugar de *vayamos*, en contextos que exigen subjuntivo y sin que exista, en el enunciado, intención exhortativa: «Tenemos una excelente relación [...]. Pero no es que vamos juntos para el cine» (Universal [Ven.] 3.9.96); debió decirse *no es que vayamos*.

The main reason is that it is a vestige of some medieval use. It is worth noting that, while "vamos" is validly used for imperative, it is wrong to use it as subjunctive.

- Dale, vamos juntos al cine (= Dale, vayamos juntos al cine): CORRECT
- No es que vamos juntos para el cine (better: No es que **vayamos** juntos al cine)

Comment: What about the negative imperative that also uses subjunctive form? i.e. is "*no vamos juntos al cine*" right?

Comment: No, in negative you need the subjunctive: *No vayamos juntos al cine, vayamos separados.*

Comment: I don't think this really helps. It goes back into history unnecessarily, and it doesn't really get us any closer to *why*.

Comment: @aparente001 If you fail to see the importance of history in the development of a language, there will be many things you will be unable to explain. Like tradition, linguistic uses pass from one generation to another. There might be, in favor of "vamos", a reason of economy -- it's simply shorter and simpler than "vayamos". If both are allowed, why use the longer? Where its use is allowed as an alternative of "vayamos", it is simply preferred by the speaker, just as the present is usually preferred over the future in a sentence like: "Mañana vamos a la fiesta".